# Why aren't Haskell variables polymorphic when bound by pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, type-inference

Consider a variable introduced in a pattern, such as `f` in this Haskell example:

```
case (\x -> x) of f -> (f True, f 'c')
```

This code results in a type error ("Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Char’"), because of the two different uses of `f`. It shows that the inferred type of `f` is not polymorphic in Haskell.

But why shouldn't `f` be polymorphic?

I have two points of comparison: OCaml and "textbook" Hindley-Milner. Both suggest that `f` ought to be polymorphic.

1. In OCaml, the analogous code is not an error:

   ```
   match (fun x -> x) with f -> (f true, f 'c')
   ```

   This evaluates to `(true, 'c')` with type `bool * char`. So it looks like OCaml gets along fine with assigning `f` a polymorphic type.
2. We can gain clarity by stripping things down to the fundamentals of Hindley-Milner - lambda calculus with "let" - which both Haskell and OCaml are based on. When reduce to this core system, of course, there is no such thing as pattern matching. We can draw parallels though. Between "let" and "lambda", `case expr1 of f -> expr2` is much closer to `let f = expr1 in expr2` than to `(lambda f. expr2) expr1`. "Case", like "let", syntactically restricts `f` to be bound to `expr1`, while a function `lambda f. expr2` doesn't know what `f` will be bound to since the function has no such restriction on where in the program it will be called. This was the reason why let-bound variables are generalized in Hindley-Milner and lambda-bound variables are not. It appears that the same reasoning that allows let-bound variables to be generalized shows that variables introduced by pattern matching could be generalized too.

The examples above are minimal for clarity, so they only show a trivial pattern `f` in the pattern matching, but all the same logic extends to arbitrarily complex patterns like `Just (a:b:(x,y):_)`, which can introduce multiple variables that would all be generalized.

Is my analysis correct? In Haskell specifically - recognizing that it's not just plain Hindley-Milner and not OCaml - why don't we generalize the type of `f` in the first example?

Was this an explicit language design decision, and if so, what were the reasons? (I note that [some in the community think that not even "let" should be generalized](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tldi10-vytiniotis.pdf), but I would imagine the design decision pre-dates that paper.)

If variables introduced in a pattern were made polymorphic similar to "let", would that break compatibility with other aspects of Haskell in a significant way?

Comment: It's worth noting that with `newtype PolyEndo = Endo {runEndo :: ∀ a . a -> a}`, you can write `case Endo id of Endo f -> (f True, f 'a')`. That makes it hardly less strange that it doesn't work without the wrapper, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assign a polymorphic type (`forall x. t`) to a case scrutinee, then it matches no non-trivial pattern, so there's no point for having `case`.

Could we generalize in some other useful way? Not really, because of GHC's lack of support for "impredicative" instantiation. In your example of `Just (a:b:(x,y):_)`, not a single bound variable can have polymorphic type, since `Maybe`, `(,)`, and `[]` cannot be instantiated with such types.

One thing works, as mentioned in the comments: data types with polymorphic fields, such as `data Endo = Endo (forall a. a -> a)`. However, type checking for polymorphic fields doesn't technically involve a generalization step, nor does it behave like let-generalization.

In principle, generalization could be performed at many points, for example even at arbitrary function arguments (e.g. in `f (\x -> x)`). However, too much generalization clogs up type inference by introducing untractable higher-rank types; this can be also understood as eliminating useful type dependencies between different parts of the program by removing unsolved metavariables. Although there are systems which can handle higher-rank inference much better than GHC, most notably [MLF](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/mlf/), they're also much more complicated and haven't seen much practical use. I personally prefer to not have silent let-generalization at all.

Answer (score 2):

One first issue is that with type classes, generalization is not always free. Consider `show :: forall a. Show a => a -> String` and this expression:

```
case show of
  f -> ...
```

If you generalize `f` to `f :: forall a. Show a => a -> String`, then GHC will pass a `Show` dictionary at every call of `f`, instead of once at the single occurrence of `show`. In case there are multiple calls all at the same type, this duplicates work compared to not generalizing.

It is also not actually a generalization of the current type inference algorithm when combined with type classes: it can cause existing programs to no longer typecheck. For example,

```
    case show of
      f -> f () ++ f mempty
```

By not generalizing `f`, we can infer that `mempty` has type `()`. On the other hand, generalizing `f :: forall a. Show a => a -> String` will lose that connection, and the type of `mempty` in that expression will be ambiguous.

It is true though that these are minor issues, and maybe things would be mostly fine with some monomorphism restrictions, even if not entirely backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, there's a reason for how type variables are treated in pattern matches in terms of the interaction with existential types.  Let's take a look at a couple definitions from [`Data.Functor.Coyoneda`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Coyoneda f a where
    Coyoneda :: (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a

lowerCoyoneda :: Functor f => Coyoneda f a -> f a
lowerCoyoneda (Coyoneda g x) = fmap g x
```

`Coyoneda` has an existential type variable used by both arguments to the constructor. If GHC doesn't pin that type down, there's no way for the `fmap` in `lowerCoyoneda` to type-check. GHC needs to know that `g` and `x` have the appropriate relation in their types, and that requires fixing the type variable in the pattern match.